# Django multiple success urls

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.8

How can I set multiple success urls using kwargs or something else?

I want, depending on what button clicked a different success URL.

- Save = Go to a DetailView
- save&continue = Stay in this UpgradeView
- save&createNew = Go to a CreateView

It should be working later exactly like in the Django admin

I have this UpdateView:

```
class TopicEditView(UpdateView):
    fields = ['title','description',]
    model = Topic

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        if data.get('save', False):
            pass
        elif data.get('save_and_continue', False):
            pass
        ...
        return UpdateView.post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('topic_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
```

And this simple template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern" name="save"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Speichern & weiter" 
        name="save_and_continue"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `get_success_url` method, check for the value of the submit button in `self.request.POST`, and return the appropriate url:

```
def get_success_url(self):
    if self.request.POST.get('save'):
        return reverse('success_url_for_save')
    elif self.request.POST.get('save_and_continue'):
        return reverse('success_url_for_save_and_continue', kwargs={'pk':self.object.pk})
    else:
        return reverse('fallback_success_url')
```

Checking the values in the `post` method shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this was a lot easier when I realized, that I still have my kwargs in self.request.POST.get. I first thought I had to set them again, thats why I had the if clause in the post method.